# implicit block passed gives local jump error

Tags: ruby

```
def my_function(&block)
  p block.call                                #1
  # lambda{return "inside the block"}.call    #2
end

p my_function{return "implicit block"}
```

Why is line 1 giving a LocalJumpError(Its saying unexpected return)?

Although according to me line 1 and line 2 are basically the same thing.The `block` variable here is a proc object and so is a lambda.
Shouldn't they also behave the same. line 2 once uncommented doesn't seem to give an error

@Andre

```
def my_function(&block)
  p block.call                                #1
  # lambda{return "inside the block"}.call    #2
end

def abc
 p my_function{return "implicit block"}
end

abc
```

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: About your edit: yes, it works.

Comment: Why would you need this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many differences between Lambda and Proc, as you can see in this [post](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/) for example.

One of them is how the `return` behaves in each case.

When you `return` in a Proc, it will return from the method it is being called.

And when you `return` in a Lambda it returns only to outside the lambda code.

The reason for the `LocalJumpError` is simply because you are you're calling `return` probably from your ruby console and there is no enclosing method to return. So if you surround your code with a method and call it, it will work.

```
def test
  def my_function(&block)
    p block.call
  end

  p my_function{ return "implicit block" }
end

test

=> "implicit block"
```

Comment: You said "When you return in a block (Proc), it will return from the method it is being called". But I am returning and also shouldn't that return value be the argument to p. I mean why does it require a new method to return. Proc.new or lambda doesn't require that. I can't seem to get this.

Comment: When you call `my_function{ return "implicit block" }` (with Proc) it will trigger a `return` in the method that's being called. If it is not inside any method, it will launch that exception you said before. You could simply remove the `return` so the last expression will be the return of the block and you won't have any problems related to that, like that `my_function{ "implicit block" }`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ block and `Proc` are totally different concepts. `block` in MRI is created directly on stack, while `Proc` instances are plain old good ruby objects. The **only** difference between lambdas and procs is that `lambda` restricts the arity, while `proc` does not. That’s it. Blocks are completely different.

Comment: Thank you, I will fix some things in my answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes I noticed that..  `                                                        
    `def my_function(&block)
      # p block.call                                #1
      p Proc.new {return "proc"}.call
      # lambda{return "inside the block"}.call    #2
    end

p my_function{return "implicit block"}
`  This seems to work. If block and Proc would have been same then Proc.new would also have given an error right? Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: @jayantihari yes, more or less. This behavior is _heavily_ depends on what ruby implementation is used. For MRI it is correct, JRuby and Rubinius behave completely different. One should avoid using `return` in ruby in general (save for early returns in methods,) and in lambdas in particular.

Comment: "When you return in a Proc, it will return from the method it is being called" -- no, the method where the proc was created returns.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def my_function(&block)
>   p block.call                                #1
>   # lambda{return "inside the block"}.call    #2
> end
>
> p my_function{return "implicit block"}
> ```
>
> Why is line 1 giving a LocalJumpError(Its saying unexpected return)?

A block (and a `Proc`) `return` from their enclosing methods. In your example, there is no enclosing method (the block literal is at the top-level), therefore there is nothing to `return` from.

Lambdas OTOH `return` from themselves, just like methods.

> ```
> def my_function(&block)
>   p block.call                                #1
>   # lambda{return "inside the block"}.call    #2
> end
>
> def abc
>   p my_function{return "implicit block"}
> end
>
> abc
> ```
>
> Shouldn't this work?

Yes, it should, and it does.

For completeness' sake: there are *two* differences between methods / lambdas and blocks / `Proc`s:

- Blocks and `Proc`s `return` from their enclosing methods, lambdas and methods `return` from themselves.
- Blocks and `Proc`s use loose argument binding with semantics that are similar to assignment (in fact, prior to Ruby 1.9, they used assignment semantics), lambdas and methods use strict argument binding.

Here's a kind-of stupid mnemonic I use: "block" and `Proc` rhyme and they behave the same, "method" and "lambda" are both Greek words and they behave the same.